Spring Boot mapping certain path to static resources
i was starting a server app (similar RestController things) and didn't want to have a token in the path like "/api/". So my Controller(s) is catching everything including my resource request ;-(
Is there a way to define a pattern like "/content/**" that is always treated as a reqource request an never routet to my Controllers ?
Update 9.10. 13:49
it's maybe a duplicate to this thread. But if i add
spring:
  mvc.static-path-pattern: /content/**

in my application.yml, the request https://example.com/content/index.html is still routet to a @Controller instead of my static resource.

The default catch-all is static resources, so unless you added a /** yourself it should automatically search for static resources already.

As stated, if you have a controller mapped to /** that acts as a catch all.

The problematic controller in this case is annotated with:
@GetMapping(
value = "/{userId:^.*(?!content)}/{objectId}",
headers = {"Accept=text/html"}, produces = "application/ld+json" )

Which is more or less /**.

yes, this means that there is no way to give static content a prefix to bypass controllers that use “/**” ;-)

The static resource handling is the last one to be consulted but this will only happen if nothing else has consumed the request. In your case your controller will resolve it and expose content as the userId and index.html to objectId. I'm not sure if your regexp is right  either.

I thing i got it working with:
value = "/{userId:(?!.*content).+}/{objectId}"
We will see, which useCases i forget ;-)

why your mappings needs to be so complicated....

See the comments above, there is no simple way to do that!
I thing i got it working with:
value = "/{userId:(?!.*content).+}/{objectId}"
We will see, which useCases i forget ;-)
